# Dismiss popover from a table selection

Tags: objective-c

I'm sorry if this duplicates other threads. I've pored through about a dozen, over several hours, but none seem to quite apply to my situation. Namely;

1. A button presents a popover
2. The popover contains a table view, nested inside a navigation controller
3. The user navigates to the second level of the nav controller (a second tableViewController), then makes a selection
4. Upon making the selection, the popover should dismiss, and pass back the indexPath.row to the original screen.

Importantly, I'm using storyboards and segues to do this (this may be part of the problem!)

I've tried implementing custom delegate methods to do this, but I'm getting hopelessly tangled up. Mainly because

a) The actual delegate is two levels away, and I'm having trouble conveying this "up the chain", as it were.
b) The [segue destinationViewController] is the navigationController. I'm not sure how to get a hook into the actual tableViews it contains, to retrieve or set properties (such as the delegate)

Does this make any sense to anyone? Reading back, this question is almost as bamboozled as I am. If you can decipher it, and have any advice, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get to the actual view controller (which has your table view) using the viewControllers property of your navigation controller (`segue.destinationViewController`). Once you have a pointer to this view controller, set its delegate. Then in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, notify the delegate that something was selected, and the delegate can dismiss the popover.

**EDIT:** This could be in your prepareForSegue:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController; // cast the destination to UINavigationController

SpeciesTableViewController *speciesViewController = [navigationController.viewControllers lastObject];
speciesViewController.delegate = self;
```

Apple docs about the `viewControllers` property of a UINavigationController:

> The view controllers currently on the navigation stack. . . . The root
>   view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view controller
>   is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1, where n is
>   the number of items in the array.

When using a segue, the root view controller is the only view controller, so lastObject always returns the root view controller.

Now, keep in mind that when you select a species in SpeciesTableViewController, you're triggering a segue, and will have to set the delegate of SpeciesDetailViewController. In SpeciesDetailViewController's `didSelectRowForIndexPath` you can send a message to the delegate to dismiss the popover.

Comment: Thanks for that. I haven't explored NSNotificationCentre, so that might be the go. In terms of delegates, the problem I have is that I don't have a class for the navigation controller that is (segue.destinationViewController

Comment: It's just a UINavigationController.

Comment: - it's just set up in the storyboard. I could create one, and set it up to receive the delegate, but I don't know how to reference the tableViewController it contains, because it's set up in the storyboard. To get it to work this way (passing the delegate around the stack) would I have to abandon the storyboard and do it all programmatically? Or am I missing something?

Comment: If I understand your situation correctly, you can still use storyboards. In prepareForSegue, segue.destinationViewController is either a UINavigationController, or your custom class that probably inherits from UITableViewController. Post a screenshot of the relevant view controllers in the storyboard and I'll give you some sample code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Scott. Here is a link. http://www.yadda.com.au/storyboard.jpg 

Pretty vanilla, I think. The navigationController is definitely the (segue.destinationViewController), rather than the nestled speciesTableViewController (checked this by NSLogging it). 

That's where the problem begins, as the navController doesn't exist in my code, and even if it did, I don;t know how to reference the tableViewController.

Comment: I figured that would be the kind of setup. The navigation controller does exist, but not in your code: you created it in the storyboard, and all you needed was getting a reference to it in your code. See my edited answer for some sample code.

Comment: Excellent. I get it. Thanks so much for seeing this through.